# Nginx - Redirect all to specific endpoint

Tags: node.js, nginx

I have some trouble to configure my Nginx to rewrite all the requests to a specific endpoint.

I have a Nodejs app running in port 8080 and I would like all the 
http://SERVER_IP/* requests to show http://127.0.0.1:8080/statuscheck

I tried (in the /etc/nginx/sites-available/default file):

```
location / {
    rewrite ^.*$ /statuscheck last;
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
}
```

But I got 500. The error logs show:

```
[error] 25756#0: *115803 rewrite or internal redirection cycle while processing "/statuscheck"
```

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The regular expression in your `rewrite` directive also matches `/statuscheck` so any rewrite or redirect that causes the expression to be evaluated more than once will cause a loop. That includes the flag parameters: `last`, `redirect` and `permanent`.

However, the `break` flag parameter stops processing `rewrite` directives and continues processing the URL within the current location. For example:

```
location / {
    rewrite ^ /statuscheck break;
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
}
```

See [this document](http://location%20/%20%7B%20%20%20%20%20rewrite%20%5E.*$%20/statuscheck%20last;%20%20%20%20%20proxy_pass%20http://127.0.0.1:8080;%20%7D) for details.

Comment: Thanks! That's exactly what I wanted!